# Android studio components installation fails on a mac

Tags: android, android-studio

On a mac, installing the latest android studio components fails, with the following error:

> Preparing "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)".
>   Downloading
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
>   "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)" failed.
>   Preparing "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision:
>   4)". Downloading
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-26_r04.zip
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-26_r04.zip
>   "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 4)"
>   failed.
>
> java.io.IOException: Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK Warning: An error occurred while
>   preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK. java.io.IOException: Cannot
>   download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-26_r04.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK Warning: An error occurred while
>   preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image: Cannot
>   download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-26_r04.zip':
>   Read timed out , response: 200 OK.

I am not sure why it times out, as I am on a 40Mb down connection.

Anything I can do?

Note: this is a freshly downloaded android studio installation, not an upgrade or anything

Comment: You could download the links yourself and move them to the SDK directory

Answer (score 0):

The logs shows you've got some kind of network error.
If you got a popup asking to allow Java internet connectivity you should allow it

> Read timed out , response: 200 OK Warning: An error occurred while
>   preparing SDK package Android Support